# When calling stored procedure, .hasRows keeps staying "false"

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which I am calling which will return data from a table.

But when I try to populate an .aspx with the data it skips my method from doing it because my method is based on whether a reader detects rows.

Here is my method:

```
private void editExhibit(int expenseID)//new
{
  saveExhibitBtn.Text = "Update Exhibit";

  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OSCIDConnectionString"].ToString());
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("p_CaseFiles_Exhibits_RetrieveExhibitDetails", conn);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExhibitID", expenseID);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExhibitID", SqlDbType.Int));
  cmd.Parameters["@ExhibitID"].Value = expenseID;

  bool hasAttachments = false;
  string investigatorID = "";
  //bool alreadyInvoiced = false;
  bool isExpenseOwner = false;
  string fileID = "-1";

  try
  {
      conn.Open();
      var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if (reader.HasRows)//////////////////////craps out here bcause hasRows is false....
      {
          reader.Read();
          fileID = reader["FileID"].ToString();
          ddlCaseFiles.SelectedValue = fileID;
          ddlCaseFiles.Enabled = false;
          // retrieve exhibit details here
          hasAttachments = (bool)reader["HasAttachments"];
          investigatorID = reader["InvestigatorID"].ToString();
          if (Session["InvestigatorID"].ToString() == investigatorID)
          {
              isExpenseOwner = true;
          }
          txtDateReceived.Value = reader["SeizeDate"].ToString();
          ddlReceivedBy.SelectedValue = reader["SeizedByInvestigatorID"].ToString();
          txtTimeReceived.Value = reader["SeizeTime"].ToString();
          txtWhyHowReceived.Value = reader["SeizeAuthority"].ToString();
          txtReceivedLocation.Value = reader["SeizeLocation"].ToString();
          txtOurItemNum.Value = reader["NewExhibitOutItemNumber"].ToString();////////////
          txtTheirItemNum.Value = reader["ClientItemNum"].ToString();
          txtBagNum.Value = reader["BagNumber"].ToString();
          txtBoxNum.Value = reader["BoxNumber"].ToString();
          txtComment.Value = reader["ExhibitDecriptionPlainText"].ToString();
      }
  }
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
      ErrorLogger.Log(ex.Number, "NewExhibit.aspx - editExhibit - Retrieve Details", ex.Message);
  }
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[p_CaseFiles_Exhibits_RetrieveExhibitDetails]
  @FilterField nvarchar(max)=null
, @FilterQuery nvarchar(max)=null
, @SortName nvarchar(max)='SeizeDate, SeizeTime '
, @SortOrder nvarchar(max)='desc'
, @ExhibitID int
as
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
declare @Command nvarchar(max)
Select @Command = 'select E.ExhibitID,convert(nvarchar,SeizeDate,111) as ''SeizeDate'',SeizeTime,ExhDesc,E.InvestigatorID as ''EnteredBy'' 
  ,E.SeizedByInvestigatoID as ''SeizedBy'',SBI.ActiveInvestigator, SBI.FName+'' '' + SBI.LName as ''SeizedByName'', E.FileID,[FileName]
  ,Investigators.FName,Investigators.LName,SzAuthority,Location,ItemID,SubItemID1,SubItemID2,SubItemID3,PageSerial,ClientItemNum,Privileged
  ,Private,E.HasAttachments,ItemEntryGradeID,BagNumber,BoxNumber,PL.PropertyId,P.PropertyTypeID,P.PropertyMakeID,P.PropertyModelID,SerialNumber,ColorID
  ,cast(ItemID as varchar)+''-''+cast(SubItemID1 as varchar)+''-''+cast(SubItemID2 as varchar)+''-''+cast(SubItemID3 as varchar) as ''ItemNumber'',StoredLocally 
  from CaseFileExhibits E 
  join Investigators on E.InvestigatorID = Investigators.InvestigatorID 
  join Investigators SBI on SBI.InvestigatorID=E.SeizedByInvestigatoID 
  join CaseFiles on E.FileID = CaseFiles.FileID 
  left join CaseFileExhibitPropertyLink PL on E.ExhibitID=PL.ExhibitID 
  left join Element09a_Properties P on P.PropertyID=PL.PropertyId 
  left join ElementPropertyTypes PT on PT.PropertyTypeID=P.PropertyTypeID 
  left join ElementPropertyMakes PM on PM.PropertyMakeID=P.PropertyMakeID 
  left join ElementPropertyModels PMD on PMD.PropertyModelID=P.PropertyModelID 
  where E.ExhibitID='+convert(nvarchar,@ExhibitID);
if(@FilterQuery is not null)
begin
  select @Command+=' and '+@FilterField+ ' like '''+@FilterQuery+''' ';
end
select @Command+=' order by '+@SortName+' '+@SortOrder
```

So according to the stored procedure I only need to pass in the `exhibitID`, which I did.

Comment: Silly question, but does running the StoredProcedure using the SQL management studio have results?

Comment: hehe Thank fully I have. And yes it does

Comment: Please show how you are calling the stored procedure in the sql management studio. You might have to call it using named parameters like: exec p_CaseFiles_Exhibits_RetrieveExhibitDetails @ExhibitID = 'SOMETHING'. Also, see my answer below

Comment: You also might want to consider optimizing this stored procedure. You could try loading the results in a table variable which would allow sql-server to compile your query which will make it run faster on subsequent calls and then using the dynamic sql to achieve your sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Stored procedure looks incomplete. You probably need to add

```
exec sp_executesql @command;
```

At the end to get it to return your rows.

info about sp_executesql can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Worked. Can you explain the SP_ExecuteSQL please? I have to wait 6 minutes before I can mark your answer as the answer

Comment: In short you have your sql in a string and in your case all SP_executesql does is execute the sql saved in that string. I added the MSDN reference to my answer